# Parsing Array<String> in Hive using OPEN CSV SEREDE

Tags: hive

I am getting data in below format :

100|15|N-PS-GL-PSJOB|**1,A|JFGLFX48**|**"AAAA"**|102

100|15|N-PS-GL-PSJOB|**2,A|JFGLFX48**|***"AAEE"***|102

100|15|N-PS-GL-PSJOB|**1,A|JFGLFX48**|**"AXXX"**|102

100|15|N-PS-GL-PSJOB|**2,A|JFGLFX48**|**"ABCH"**|102

I need to implement

1. parse with "|" and  split fourth column value using **','**
2. remove quotes

I used array as datatype for 4th column and opencsvserede to remove quotes.But how can I pass split method(COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ',') inside opencsv serede.

ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES("separatorChar" = "|","quoteChar" = "\"")

Thanks
Surya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be couple of ways to solve this. The best option will be to pre-process this data in a hive landing table and then load the resultant data to a destination hive table that may be ORC/PARQUET file type that yields you better performance than plain text read via serde.

**Create Landing table pointing to your text data**

```
create external table landing (c1 string, c2 string, c3 string, c4 string, c5 string, c6 string, c7 string) row format delimited fields terminated by '|' location '/user/hdfs/landing';
```

**Create destination table**

```
create external table destination(c1 string,c2 string,c3 string,c4 string,c5 string,c6 string ,c7 string,c8 string) stored as orc location '/user/hdfs/destination';
```

**Insert data to destination selecting records from landing**

```
insert into destination select c1, c2, c3, split(c4,',')[0] , split(c4,',')[1] ,c5, regexp_replace(c6,'\"','') , c7 from landing;
```

You can re-use the collection logic if the 4th column is supposed to be a collection. For sake of simplicity, I split them to 2 separate string columns.

If you would just want to create a view on the first table, that should also be fine. But a view is still going to execute on text data which is relatively slow than a ORC/Parquet format.

**Results**

**select * from landing**

```
100 15  N-PS-GL-PSJOB   1,A JFGLFX48    "AAAA"  102
100 15  N-PS-GL-PSJOB   2,A JFGLFX48    "AAEE"  102
100 15  N-PS-GL-PSJOB   1,A JFGLFX48    "AXXX"  102
100 15  N-PS-GL-PSJOB   2,A JFGLFX48    "ABCH"  102
```

**select * from destination**

```
100 15  N-PS-GL-PSJOB   1   A   JFGLFX48    AAAA    102
100 15  N-PS-GL-PSJOB   2   A   JFGLFX48    AAEE    102
100 15  N-PS-GL-PSJOB   1   A   JFGLFX48    AXXX    102
100 15  N-PS-GL-PSJOB   2   A   JFGLFX48    ABCH    102
```

Other options being :-

```
select c1, c2, c3, split(c4,',')[0] , split(c4,',')[1] ,c5, regexp_replace(c6,'\"','') , c7 from t1;
```

Or if you want to hide the complexity of the replace and split from the query, just create a view with the same query

```
create view landingview as select c1, c2, c3, split(c4,',')[0] , split(c4,',')[1] ,c5, regexp_replace(c6,'\"','') , c7 from landing;
```

Both of which yields the same result

```
100 15  N-PS-GL-PSJOB   1   A   JFGLFX48    AAAA    102
100 15  N-PS-GL-PSJOB   2   A   JFGLFX48    AAEE    102
100 15  N-PS-GL-PSJOB   1   A   JFGLFX48    AXXX    102
100 15  N-PS-GL-PSJOB   2   A   JFGLFX48    ABCH    102
```

Comment: Thanks Ak. That's works perfectly. But I am getting one more issue. Few values are only one word, so while splitting the second column and blank values are getting NULL values.   Please find below details :  Input data :  HIVEVA

Comment: You would need to use a case statement to address this